# Не ничего не выводит курсор

Tags: база-данных, oracle

Делаю курсов в sqldeveloper, но он ничего не выводит. Пишет 
`Procedure ROUTECOST compiled` и все. Где я ошибся?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE routecost(distance varchar) AS
        CURSOR cur IS
        SELECT * FROM route;
        ID_ro INT;
        destin varchar(30);
        depart date;
        route_num INT;
        days_of_mov date;
        dist varchar(30);
        ticket_p number;
        ID_sto INT;
        Kyrensy INT;
    BEGIN
        IF distance = '21457 км' THEN
            Kyrensy := 500;
        ELSIF distance = '5471 км' THEN
            Kyrensy := 200;
        ELSIF distance = '589635 км' THEN
            Kyrensy := 100;
        END IF;
        OPEN cur;
        FETCH cur INTO ID_ro, destin, depart, route_num, days_of_mov, dist, ticket_p, ID_sto;
        WHILE cur%FOUND LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Цена за билет ' || TO_CHAR(ID_ro) || ' ровна ' || TO_CHAR(ticket_p+Kyrensy) || ' ' || distance);
            FETCH cur INTO ID_ro, destin, depart, route_num, days_of_mov, dist, ticket_p, ID_sto;
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE cur;
    END routecost;
```

Comment: а там нет отдельной вкладочки для output в этом девелопере?

Comment: нет, он обычно пишет `Procedure ROUTECOST compiled` а затем выводит содержимое.

Comment: Ааа...так вы создали процедуру, но не запускали ее?

Comment: А по подробнее можно? Я не совсем понял

Comment: Код в вопросе - это код процедуры. То есть вы описали то, как она должна себя вести. Теперь ее надо еще запустить на выполнение

Comment: в другом окне например `begin routecost('21457 км') end;`

Comment: Это вроде имя процедуры и ее параметры?

Comment: `/` после процедуры еще поставьте.

Comment: 1) varchar2 правильно, varchar зарезервированно для лучших времён, это когда `length ('')` вернёт 0, а не null. Так же int это constrained datatype, почему не использовать number? Зачем столько переменных? Достаточно  одной типа `route%rowtype`. 2)  `set serveroutput on size unlimited` так же работает, выводит в стандартное окно для скриптов. Dmitry поправте ответ.  3) Запускать проще так `exec routecost ('21457 км')` 4) / в SqlDev не обязательно, можно выделить и запустить.

Comment: О чём собственно вопрос? Что вы пытались сделать? Какого результата ожидали? Например, если вопрос по работе с sqldeveloper, то надо добавиить соответствующую метку. Если вопрос по прцедуре, то также не хватает метки plsql.

Answer (score 1):

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` в вашем коде - это команда для SQLPlus. Вряд ли вы работаете в нем, так что эту строку можно смело выкинуть. То, что идет дальше - это код для создания и компиляции процедуры. Он ничего не запускает. Чтобы запустить процедуру на выполнение, надо написать, например, анонимный блок для ее вызова:

```
begin
  routecost('123 км');
end;
/
```

Запустить код можно кнопкой <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Далее, как увидеть вывод:

1. Меню `View` -> `DBMS Output`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Появится новое окошко, в котором надо нажать на <kbd>+</kbd>, а потом выбрать соединение в маленьком окошке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также ообратите внимание на Buffer Size - это максимально возможное количество символов для вывода. Если процедура выведет больше, возникнет исключение. Если не хватает, поставьте число побольше перед запуском. Но обычно хватает.

3. Потом надо выделить код анонимного блока (выше) и нажать кнопку "запустить":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `set serveroutput on` так же работает в sqldev и выводит в стандартное окно для скриптов. Поправте ответ.